# Jquery Cloning a Menu of HTML Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clone a series of buttons on the bottom of my app. I want the user to have access to the menu when they are scrolled all the way down as well.

the problem arises when i add event handlers to the buttons using their ID. It seems the duplicate IDS are not working. The first instance of the menu works but the one below doesn't work.

I guess I'm asking are duplicate ID's a no no and If so how do I get around this. Using classes to target the buttons?

thanks,

-Laurence

Comment: IDs aren't supposed to be duplicated.

Comment: You're right, you should never have duplicate ID's, and using classes as your suggested is a good idea.

Comment: duplicate IDs are a no-no, but you could use dedicated class names for your buttons.

Comment: oh well, at least the bronze medal for me... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use classes to provide functionality to your buttons. So, you would need to add the same class to the duplicate buttons. Then you can add an event to the classes. But, there is no way to do multiple IDs.

You could also have the same name and then check on the server side what button was pressed. I don't know your setup or what you are trying to do, but that could be a possibility as well.

The other thing you can do is have the buttons scroll with the page. So you can keep it at the top of the page while you are scrolling. Then you don't have to worry about trying to duplicate any buttons.

If you have GMail you can see what i mean by scrolling with the page. If you scroll down in your inbox, you will see the toolbar scroll down too.